# C++ -- how to call user defined operator?

Tags: c++

I saw the following code snippet:

```
class WindowHandle {
public:
  WindowHandle(WINDOW_HANDLE handle) : w(handle) {}
  ~WindowHandle() { destoryWindow(w); }

  operator WINDOW_HANDLE() { return w; }
  ...

private:
  WINDOW_HANDLE w;
  ...
}
```

Here is the question: how do I use operator WINDOW_HANDLE() to get the raw pointer? I list my guess as follows:

```
WindowHandle win(createWindow());

WINDOW_HANDLE winPtr = win.operator WINDOW_HANDLE(); // I am not sure whether this is correct.
```

Thank you

Comment: Is that code even valid C++??

Comment: @alpha123 - it looks like it's a cast operator with a macro for the type...

Comment: I wrote WINDOW_HANDLE winPtr = win.operator WINDOW_HANDLE() and just try to figure out how to use this user defined operator.

Comment: @alpha123: Yes it's valid, at least up to the point he tries to use it.  @Thief: C++ most definitely allows user-defined conversions, and the `operator` keyword is used when writing a conversion FROM your type (conversions TO your type are created using constructors).

Comment: @awoodland, @Ben Voigt: Thanks. :) I rarely use C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply

```
WINDOW_HANDLE winPtr = win;
```

is sufficient.  User-defined operators create implicit conversions.

Comment: Hello Ben, what if the class WindowHandle defines more than one user defined operators and how does the compiler knows which one to pick? -- thank you

Comment: @q0987: This is the only case where C++ uses the return type in overload resolution.

Comment: @q0987 - it picks an appropriate one for the assignment/conversion at hand.

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to cast:

```
WINDOW_HANDLE winPtr = static_cast<WINDOW_HANDLE>(win);
```

Comment: Don't use casts when they're not necessary, that just prevents the compiler from warning you if you did something wrong.  There is no warning here with or without a cast.

Comment: WoW, I think this should be my answer:) anyone to confirm?

Comment: @Ben, you are absolutely right. We should avoid this kind of code as mentioned by the book author. -- thank you

Comment: @Ben - static cast like that seems to be the safest of un-needed casts possible and it *does* make what's happening quite a bit clearer to the reader (i.e. not using a constructor for winPtr other than the copy constructor)

Comment: @awoodland: I try not to write bad code just because it's less bad than other bad code.  And I try to encourage good code in my answers and comments here.

Comment: @Ben, can you confirm whether or not the answer by Benjamin is valid for my answer? -- thank you

Comment: @q0987 - the other Ben's answer is better.

Comment: @q9087: B. Lindley's answer will work, but it's less than ideal because it turns off warnings about incompatible types.  If you were casting to the wrong type, for example, the compiler would just do what you told it without complaint.  On the other hand the version I suggested requires a user-defined conversion to exist.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not really sure what you mean about turning off warnings for incompatible types.  Could you provide an example to clarify that please?

Comment: @Benjamin: Ok: `DialogHandle wnd(CreateDialog()); WINDOW_HANDLE wnd = static_cast<WINDOW_HANDLE>(wnd);` ... The variable type got changed (potentially in another file entirely), and now the compiler isn't going to let you know there's a problem on this line.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the code you are showing is to automatically close a handle. Thus you make a call that creates a WINDOW_HANDLE and you put it into the wrapper class which will close it for you.

The main issue is that it has an implicit constructor, no overloaded copy-constructor or assignment operator, and its destructor destroys the handle.

Thus you could well get into trouble with that implementation.

The purpose of the operator WINDOW_HANDLE (which is legal, ThiefMaster, it's an implicit conversion), is to allow the user to pass a WindowHandle into a function that actually requires a WINDOW_HANDLE. The conversion should be a const method. (It is not passing a reference, after all).

Although the language has given you such a feature it is preferable not to use it. A `get()` method is preferable.

There is no need to write code like this as you can use `boost::unique_ptr` for this purpose if you do not need it to be copyable and boost::shared_ptr if you do, and in either case you create it with a deleter function, in this case `DestroyWindow`

Comment: You're definitely right about the copy-constructor and assignment operator.  OTOH the asker mentioned that he's using a code snippet from Scott Meyer, who certainly knows the rule of three, so I suspect those are hidden in the ellipsis.  I'm not sure how the smart pointer classes would deal with this, as the contained value isn't a pointer type, so what would you choose for a template actual parameter?